# convert a wav file to a txt file

Tags: java, audio, wav

thanks for reading this
Well what I'm trying to do is to take a .wav file (only a short audio) and convert it to ints, and every one represent a tone of the audio...
If you're asking why I'm doing this, is because I'm doing an arduino project, and I want to make the arduino to play a song, and for doing that I need an int array where every int is a tone.
So I thought, "well if I program a little application to convert any .wav file to a txt where are stored the ints that represent the melody notes, I just need to copy this values to the arduino project code";
So after all this, maybe you're asking "What is your problem?";
I done the code and is "working", the only problem is that the txt only have "1024" in each line...
So it's obviously that I'm having a problem, no all the tones are 1024 -_-

```
package WaveToText;

import java.io.*;

/**
*
* @author  Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez
* @project This porject is to convert a wav music files to a int array
*          Which is going to be printed in a txt file to be used for an arduino
* @serial  1.0.1 (05/11/201)
*/

public final class Converter 
{
/**
 * 
 * @Class Here is where is going to be allowed all the code for the application
 * 
 * @Param Text is an .txt file where is going to be stored the ints
 * @Param MyFile is the input of the wav file to be converted
 */

PrintStream Text;
InputStream MyFile;

public Converter () throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
        MyFile = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\luismiguel\\Dropbox\\ESTUDIO\\PROGRAMAS\\JAVA\\WavToText\\src\\WaveToText\\prueba.wav");
        Text = new PrintStream(new File("Notes.txt"));
}

public void ConvertToTxt() throws IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(MyFile);

    int read;

    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
    {
        Text.println(read);
    }
    Text.close();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO code application logic here
    Converter Exc = new Converter();
    Exc.ConvertToTxt();        
}
```

}

Comment: Your general approach is not quite right to begin with. WAV files store time-domain data; that is, signal vs. time (e.g. a 440 Hz tone may be, for example, sample values of a 440 Hz sine wave in the WAV file). Your concept of "tones" is frequency-domain; that is, signal strength vs. frequency. You would need to either perform some type of frequency analysis (look up discrete FFT) to extract "melody" information from the raw waveforms in a WAV file, or you would need to modify your hardware side and have the Arduino play raw digital audio instead of parameterizing the frequency.

Comment: By the way, for the file format itself, [it is well-documented](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/), and there is a good example of reading the data [here](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html). However, you are better off using an [`AudioInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html) which already does the job for you (and supports formats besides just WAV). See also http://sweb.cityu.edu.hk/sm1204/2012A/page20/index.html, which describes some FFT libraries that integrate with the Java Sound API.

Comment: whether the approach is right or not, i have provided the problem with your code in an answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well I've tried something "similar" what you (CharlieS) said, and I say similar because the output file is exactly the same, and this have a lot of different numbers, but no are realy what I was expecting; and I think is because what Alexander says,
So I'm going to try that way...
Also I tried the AudioInputStream, but I got the "UnsupportedAudioFileException"
Anyways thanks a lot guys for help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait wait wait..... a lot of things aren't right here....
You can't just read the bytes and send them to Arduino because as you are saying Arduino expects note numbers. The numbers in a Wav file are, first the "header" with audio info, and then the numbers representing discrete points in the signal (Waveform). If you want to get notes you need some algorithms for pitch detection or  music transcription.
Pitch detection could work if your music is monophonic or close to monophonic. For full band songs it would be troublesome. 
 So... 
I guess the "Arduino part" will play monophonic music, and you need to extract the fundamental frequency of the signal in particular time moment (This is called pitch detection and there are different ways to do it (autocorrelation, amdf, spectral analisys)). You must also keep the timing of the notes.
When you extract the frequencies there is a formula to convert frequency into integer number representing a note number on a piano. n=12(log2(f/440)) + 49 where n is the integer note number and f is the fundamental frequency of the note. Before calculating you should also quantize the frequencies you get from the pitch recognition algorithm to the closest (google for the exact note frequencies).

However I really suggest to do some more research. It would be really difficult to detect note in a music where you have few instruments playing, drums, singer, all together....

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
{
    Text.println(read);
}
```

This bit of code reads 1024 bytes of data from `in`, then assigns the number of bytes read to `read`, which is 1024, until the end of file.  You then print `read` to your text file.

You probably wanted to print `buff` to your text file, but that is going to write 1024 bytes, rather than the 1024 ints you want.

You will need to create a for loop to print the individual bytes as ints.

```
while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buff.length; i++) 
        Text.print((int)buff[i]);
}
```